# There appears to be a contradiction while solving recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Consider the equation :
$$
y[n]-\frac{1}{2}y[n-1]=x[n]
$$
where $x[n]:=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}u[n]$. First, I was asked to find the homogenous part of the solution having a form $y_{h}:=A\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Indeed the homogenous solution
$$
y_{h}[n]=\frac{1}{2^{n}}y[0]
$$
where I insist $A=y[0]$. Furthermore, The particular solution is given of the form $y_{p}[n]:=B\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}u[n]$ I shall determine $B$ as follow :
$$
B\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}u[n]-\frac{1}{2}B\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}u[n-1]=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}u[n]
$$
\begin{align*}
\implies B&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}u[n]}{\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}u[n]-\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}u[n-1]}\\ \\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}}{\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}-\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}}\\ \\
&=-2
\end{align*}

So now that we have $B=-2$, We are given the initial rest condition (a condition that states if $x[n]=0$, $\forall n<0$ then $y[n]=0$ $\forall n<0$). so what I did was sub $n=0$ in difference equation
$$
y[0]-\frac{1}{2}y[-1]=x[0]
$$
$$
\implies y[0]=1
$$
$$
**\text{So this means $A=y[0]=1$}**
$$
However, the major issue is that :
$$
y[0]-\frac{1}{2}y[-1]=x[0]
$$
$$
\implies y[0]=1
$$
$$
\implies y[n]:= y_{h}[n]+y_{p}[n] \implies y[0]=y_{h}[0]+y_{p}[0]=1
$$
$$
\implies A\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{0} -2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{0}=1
$$
$$
\implies A=3
$$
So I have $A=1$ and $A=3$, an obvious contradiction and I hope someone can help me.

**Remark** : $u[n]$ is the unit-step function where :
$$
u[n]:=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $n\geq0$}\\
0&\text{if $n<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I think what you're observing is that the homogeneous part of the solution with your condition is identically zero. The solution $y[n] = -\frac{2}{3^n} u[n]$ satisfies your "rest state" condition and is clearly a solution of the difference equation.

Comment: But from what I obtained, the homogenous solution part can not be $0$ knowing that $y[0]=1$ @Gregory

Comment: Then you have too many conditions. You require $y[-1] = 0$ and $y[0] = 1$ but your difference equation is first-order.

Comment: The thing is I did not assume $y[0]=1$ but I noticed that $y[0]-0.5 y[-1] = x[0]$ here $y[-1]=0$ by the rest condition but $x[0]=(1/3)^0=1$. @Gregory

Comment: The coefficient for $B$ is different if you choose $n = 0$ or $n> 0$.

Comment: Ah now I am noticing it

Comment: So which assumption must be valid? By assuming $n>1$, does this mean that $u[n]=0$ and that $B=0$?  @Gregory

Comment: I think the question is potentially ill-posed. It reminds me of Fredholm Alternative Theorem that makes claims on when $Ax = b$ has a solution. You can look for the adjoint's homogeneous solution $A^T y = 0$ and so $Ax = b$ has a solution iff $y^T b = 0$. I have a feeling that given the constraints on your problem something like this for difference equations might not be satisfied.

Comment: You are right, the problem appears to be ill posed I just noticed that $A=y[0]$ and also $y[0]=y_{h}[0]+y_{p}[0]$ so this would mean $A=A+B$ that is $B=0$. @Gregory

Answer (score 1):

The mistake that you made is that you assumed $\displaystyle y_{h}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}y[0]$ while it should be $\displaystyle y_{h}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}y_{h}[0]$. Therefore :
$$
A=y_{h}[0]
$$
Moreover, in finding the value of $B$, you have two cases $n$ starting from $0$ and $n$ starting from $1$, you should specify where $n$ starts.

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneous solution gives

$$
y_h(n) = 2^{1-n}c_0
$$

now making for the particular $y_p(n) = 2^{1-n}c_0(n)$ after substituting into the complete recurrence we have

$$
c_0(n)-c_0(n-1) = \frac{2^{n-1}}{3^n}
$$

and solving this recurrence we have

$$
c_0(n) = 1-\left(\frac23\right)^n
$$

hence

$$
y(n) = y_h(n)+y_p(n) = 2^{1-n}c_0 + 2^{1-n}\left(1-\left(\frac23\right)^n\right), \ \ \ n\ge 0
$$